# Base64 Error: The image contents is not valid base64 data java

Tags: java, android, image, magento, base64

I am streaming an image to Magento, and encoding an image using `android.util.Base64` using either of:

```
Base64.encodeToString(content, Base64.CRLF)
Base64.encodeToString(content, Base64.DEFAULT)
```

But I always receive fault:

```
The image contents is not valid base64 data
```

> Working: I found that the data had to be encoded twice, one time using
>   Base64 and another encoding using custom Library

Comment: at what point do you receive fault string? when encoding?

Comment: whehter you want to convert a image to bytearray using base64?

Comment: I assume he means that the external api responds with this message.

Comment: That was the reply from external API.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing data node from your base64 code for image.

e.g. if you have data like `data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAVQAAABXCAYAA...`
then remove data node. It should look like below and pass it to Magento.

```
iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAVQAAABXCAYAA...
```